# APK via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, 4.4-kitkat, file-transfer, apk

I recently bought a Nexus 5. I tried to send an `.apk` (via bluetooth) from my mobile to other mobile. Its working fine and I installed the app on other mobile. But when I tried to send the same `.apk` from that mobile (HTC One X) to my Nexus 5, the HTC shows "cannot send".

I am able to recieve a video from the HTC One X, but not any `.apk`. Any clue on how to receive the `.apk` via Bluetooth on my Nexus 5 from it?

Comment: Is there a more detailed error message? Also: Does it show "failed" on the sending device, or on the Nexus 5 when receiving it?

Comment: Its showing as " cannot send"

Comment: OK, so it's "the other" device. And the problem is not *receiving the `.apk`*, but *sending* it from that "other device". Could you please [edit] your question and add some details on that device (name, brand, Android version)?

Comment: I am able to recieve a video from Htc one x. But not able to recieve a apk from it

Comment: I thought apk sending was blocked via bluetooth to stop people spreading malicious applications (like sending an exe in certain Windows mail clients)? There are Play Store apps that circumvent this afaik. Edit: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33858/my-new-nexus-7-doesnt-allow-me-to-receive-apk-files-with-bluetooth One workaround there is to zip the apk and send the zip file..

Comment: Im just thinking if there is some setting in nexus 5 that will make me allow recieving apk via bluetooth.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

- Rename the `.apk` to something legitimate like `.png` or `.jpg` and send it across via bluetooth.

This should get around the in-built filter of what files can be transferred. Some, if not all, ROMs have the `.apk` extension blacklisted for obvious reasons when bluetooth is activated.

Use a filemanager of any kind, to do this for you, send the "PNG" or "JPG" across, on the other end, it will be saved, use the same filemanager on the other end to rename it back to `.apk` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not get a pop-up notification saying "Allow this transfer" when sending executable (apk) files? That happened to me but you can also try to play around in Bluetooth settings in regards to file receiving.

If you cannot get it to work, I often use AirDroid which works flawlessly.